# Hiding password entry input in python

Tags: python, passwords, tkinter

I am trying to make a little log in program. But i am not sure if there is a way to replace the "password" with stars when you type the password. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def callback():
print("hi")

top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

L1 = Label(top, text="Password")
L1.grid(row=1, column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.grid(row=1, column=1)

MyButton1 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton1.grid(row=3, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `show="*"` option. e.g.

```
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5, show="*")
```

Comment: That was easier than i thought it would be. Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 1):

You can create an entry this way
And hide it like a password

```
from tkinter import *

def show():
    entry.configure(show='')
    check.configure(command=hide, text='hide password')

def hide():
    entry.configure(show='*')
    check.configure(command=show, text='show password')


window = Tk()
window.title('The Title')
window.geometry('400x400')
window.resizable(False, False)

entry = Entry(window, show='*')
entry.pack()

check = Checkbutton(window, text='show password',
        command=show)
check.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice start, but Program need more work as is.  Return does not exit, and return the password,  nor is there an enter button.

Answer (score 0):

```
from getpass import getpass
getpass()
```

There are various alternatives to this floating around the web that have been altered to echo something, like asterisks. Unfortunately they tend to be platform-specific, unlike getpass().

Comment: This solution definitely will not work with a Tkinter entry widget. It's the wrong solution for this specific problem.