# tkinter: how to detect `Checkbutton` when GUI starts?

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is:
I created an `Entry` window for placing the login of the user. Then I created `Checkbutton` for remembering the login.

My code works when:

1. I enter the login
2. Tick the box (to be more specific: untick it and tick it again, because when don't do it in this way It won't save the login. This is part of my problem)
3. Exit the GUI
4. When I open the GUI again, the login is displayed.
   **The problem is:**
5. when I open the GUI **once again**, the login isn't displayed - and it should be - even though the `Checkbutton` is ticked (by default).

I assume that the problem is: my code doesn't detect the initial state of `Checkbutton`.
I'm looking for the solution: how to force my code to detect the initial state of the `Checkbutton` in the same manner as the user physically click/tick it ( or untick it)?

My code:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font

#global root
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1740x850")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591456/can-i-use-rgb-in-tkinter/51592104
def from_rgb(rgb):
    """translates an rgb tuple of int to a tkinter friendly color code
    """
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb   

root.title('Reproducible Example')

content = tk.Frame(root)
content.configure(bg='LightCyan2')

content.columnconfigure(0, weight=8)
content.columnconfigure(1, weight=8)
content.columnconfigure(2, weight=8)
content.columnconfigure(3, weight=8)
content.columnconfigure(4, weight=8)

content.rowconfigure(0, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(1, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(2, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(3, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(4, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(5, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(6, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(7, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(8, weight=8)
content.rowconfigure(9, weight=8)



# =============================================================================
# Button's font pattern:
# =============================================================================
font_button_big = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size="11", weight='bold')
font_button_small = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size="10", weight='bold')

# =============================================================================
# creating a window that will allow a user to place account_login login
# =============================================================================
label_entry_account_login_login = tk.Label(
        content, text="account_login Name: ",
        width=18,
        bg=from_rgb((193,254,252)),
        font=font_button_big,
        anchor="e"
        )
#L1.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
# This line allows to display text in entry: `entry_account_login_login' from txt file: 'Offer List, Clients, logins\account_login_login.txt'
account_login_login_var=tk.StringVar()

entry_account_login_login = tk.Entry(
        content,
        textvariable=account_login_login_var,
        bd =5,
        width=40
        )
#entry_account_login_login.pack()
text_account_login_name = entry_account_login_login.get()

# account_login checkbutton: `remeber login`

# load the text before startup
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979656/is-it-possible-to-make-tkinter-remember-variables-when-you-close-it
if os.path.isfile(r'Offer List, Clients, logins\account_login_login.txt'):
    with open(r'Offer List, Clients, logins\account_login_login.txt') as text_file_account_login_login:
        account_login_login_var.set(text_file_account_login_login.read())

def account_login_login_remember():
    if account_login_login_remembervar.get() == True:
        text_account_login_name = entry_account_login_login.get()
        print("text_account_login_name(true mode): ", bool(text_account_login_name)) # test
        # https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+save+input+to+text+file
        with open(r'Offer List, Clients, logins\account_login_login.txt', "w") as text_file_account_login_login:
        #Opens or creates the .txt file, sharing the directory of the script
            text_file_account_login_login.write(text_account_login_name) # Writes the variable into the .txt file # text_account_login_name
            text_file_account_login_login.close() # Closes the .txt file

account_login_login_remembervar = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)

account_login_bt_login_remeber = tk.Checkbutton(
        content,
        text="remeber login",
        variable=account_login_login_remembervar,
        onvalue=True,
        bg=from_rgb((193,254,252)),
        font=font_button_big,
        command=account_login_login_remember
        )

# =============================================================================
# creating a window that will allow a user to place account_login pass
# =============================================================================

label_entry_account_login_pass = tk.Label(
        content, text="account_login pass: ",
        width=18,
        bg=from_rgb((193,254,252)),
        font=font_button_big,
        anchor="e"
        )
#L2.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989819/hiding-password-entry-input-in-python:
entry_account_login_pass = tk.Entry(content, bd =5, width=40, show="*")
#entry_account_login_pass.pack()
text_account_login_pass = entry_account_login_pass.get()
# =============================================================================
# making "exit window" button
# =============================================================================

exit_button = tk.Button(content, 
          text='Quit', 
          command=content.quit)
# =============================================================================
# Main grid:
# =============================================================================

content.grid(column=0, row=0)
#frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6)

exit_button.grid(column=2, row=9)

label_entry_account_login_login.grid(column=1, row=1,  sticky=(tk.N))
entry_account_login_login.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(tk.N), rowspan=3)
account_login_bt_login_remeber.grid(column=3, row=1,  sticky=(tk.N))
label_entry_account_login_pass.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(tk.N))
entry_account_login_pass.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(tk.N), rowspan=3)




with open(r'Offer List, Clients, logins\account_login_login.txt','w') as text_file_account_login_login:
    text_file_account_login_login.write(text_account_login_name)
    

root.mainloop()

text_file_account_login_login.close() # Closes the .txt file
```

Comment: check what value `account_login_remembervar` is at the start of the code? (that also requires moving it to the top too), it would also be great if you provided a [mre] and I didn't quite understand what you mean by _the login isn't displayed_

Comment: Hello, I just update my code. Now the minimal reproducible example is provided. The only thing is: there is a need of creating a text file somewhere. My path was: C:\Users\b2b\Desktop\My projects\Offer List, Clients, logins\account_login_login.txt. The file `account_login_login.txt` is needed to save the login. Without it on your pc, there is no way to check my code.

Comment: I don't see any [mre] and you still didn't explain what you mean by _the login isn't displayed_. Anyhow as far as I understand you want to save the checkbutton state and load it with that state the next time the program starts?

Comment: doesn't seem **minimal**, does it? so again a [mre] would be appreciated but what exactly do you want to achieve? that the buttons state is saved and loaded the next time?

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is the updated code from my first post. I also post here a video that explains what's the core problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whcQtyfL0No

Comment: honestly, amazing video, you made it extremely clear as to what your issue is. now the reason that happens is because the command that would save the username is called once you click the checkbutton (the `command` argument, the function there is called each time the checkbutton is clicked), although it is called it also checks for the state of the checkbutton so it saves the username only if you have pressed the checkbutton AND it has the value of 1.

Comment: the usual approach however at least in the websites where I have seen this implemented is that the checkbutton itself doesn't do any saving stuff, there is usually the log in button that when pressed would check the checkbuttons state and if it is checked then would save the username and password and then login the user (or login and then save)  (or if the user has not ticked the box then simply log in)

Comment: ok. So for example, if I will add a `quit` button for my GUI, I will need to implement two definitions attached to this button: one for check the `tk.checkbutton` and another one for closing the window. So, now I know where the implementation of this "checking" should be, but still, I don't know how can I invoke this checking of `tk.checkbutton` inside the definition related to the `quit` button. PS. I will update my code from the first post once again, so it will have the quit button (it will make it all easier).

Comment: you don't need a quit button, you can assign a protocol to window as to what to do when the X is pressed but I mean that there would be a login button that would do the saving, I will write a small example

Comment: I don't know also, how to place the `content.exit` command, from `exit button`, inside a regular definition. This is because `content.exit` is Tkinter function and I don't have experience in nesting such functions inside a normal definition.

Comment: it is like any regular function, to call it you have to add parentheses: `content.quit()` if you want to simply call it

Comment: ok. So now, I just don't know how can I invoke this checking of tk.checkbutton inside the definition related to the quit button. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual method, save user data for remembering only when they log in:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button, Checkbutton, BooleanVar


# open file and read it, if previously checked to remember then the first line
# will contain the name, else it will be empty
with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    name = file.readline()


def sign_in():
    # get data from entry
    data = entry.get()
    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:  # open file in write mode
        f.write(data if var.get() else '')  # if user wanted to remember then write to file
        # the entered data else write nothing (note that this will overwrite everything in the file)
    # the login code but in this case just quit
    root.quit()  # or use `exit()` depending on what you need


root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Label(frame, text='Name:').pack(side='left')

# define entry and insert the saved name if there is a saved name
entry = Entry(frame)
entry.insert(0, name)
entry.pack(side='left')

var = BooleanVar(value=1)
Checkbutton(frame, text='Remember', variable=var).pack(side='right')

Button(root, text='Sign In', command=sign_in).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you wanted to save data on window close without them having to press anything you can do this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button, Checkbutton, BooleanVar


# open file and read it, if previously checked to remember then the first line
# will contain the name, else it will be empty
with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    name = file.readline()


def save_data():
    # get data from entry
    data = entry.get()
    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:  # open file in write mode
        f.write(data if var.get() else '')  # if user wanted to remember then write to file
        # the entered data else write nothing (note that this will overwrite everything in the file)
    root.quit()  # or use `exit()` depending on what you need


root = Tk()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', save_data) # this protocol
# is triggered when user presses the "X" button in the top right corner of window

Label(root, text='Name:').pack(side='left')

# define entry and insert the saved name if there is a saved name
entry = Entry(root)
entry.insert(0, name)
entry.pack(side='left')

var = BooleanVar(value=1)
Checkbutton(root, text='Remember', variable=var).pack(side='right')

root.mainloop()
```

Explanation is in code comments but if you have any questions, ask them!

Comment: Thank you. Your second approach is perfect. After a small modification, it works great.